# Editing long text TextView causes a 'FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION' error in Accessibility code

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView with a fairly long document in it (~1800 lines, 70k characters). The document has a number of spans applied in order to provide formatting. This all works quite well.

However, while editing text, I intermittently get the following error:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 119652)
E/AccessibilityManager: Error during sending EventType: TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED; EventTime: 67446779; PackageName: <package name>; MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0; ContentChangeTypes: []; WindowChangeTypes: [] [ ClassName: android.widget.EditText; Text: [

<ENTIRE CONTENTS OF DOCUMENT>

]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount: 78607; CurrentItemIndex: -1; Enabled: true; Password: false; Checked: false; FullScreen: false; Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: 78585; ToIndex: 78585; ScrollX: 0; ScrollY: 0; MaxScrollX: 0; MaxScrollY: 0; ScrollDeltaX: -1; ScrollDeltaY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0 
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub$Proxy.sendAccessibilityEvent(IAccessibilityManager.java:580)
E/AccessibilityManager:     at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityManager.java:606)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8618)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:1094)
        at android.view.View.requestParentSendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:8333)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:8326)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:8297)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(TextView.java:12217)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:8274)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:12206)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:8238)
        at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged(TextView.java:10488)
```

This sometimes causes the app to crash as well.

As best as I can tell, this is caused by the Accessibility Service code trying to send to much data as part of an intent.

Can anyone this of how I could prevent this. I know I could just block the accessibility code from firing (i.e. override the method in TextView), but I would rather a not potentially disrupt users who rely on accessibility.

Comment: You can try to do it in this way
https://android.jlelse.eu/best-practice-for-text-on-android-long-text-investigation-eb274acf1084
Huge text is not optimised very well, so you should use some tricks to make it rendering and feeling better

Comment: @frANTicBee This may work for a read-only TextView, but will not for an editable text view. The application I am working on is essentially a text editor.

Comment: If i'll do smth like that - i would like to make them just text and turn it into EditText only by tap on paragraph. seems that user don't need to see all 1800 lines at the time and correct all of them in a row